# How to print the pointer value (as a number) for an object in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, pointers

For logging and debugging purposes, I want to print the address of an object. When I reference the object by name only, the description method is automatically inferred, which is a string.

Is there a simple way to reference the address, as a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print pointer address use %p format specifier:

```
NSLog(@"Pointer = %p", obj);
```